# jQuery - How can I create an element based on user choice in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I'm trying to create 5 different audio players from the following code to call them out individually wherever I need it in the HTML document: https://codepen.io/katzkode/pen/ZbxYYG

The issue is that these 2 loops use a single div element to call the function (5 audio players at once):

**For audio:**

```
/* createAudioElements
 * create audio elements for each file in files */
function createAudioElements() {
    for (f in files) {
        var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/" + files[f] + "\"></audio>";
        $("#audio-players").append(audioString);
    }
}
```

**For div element:**

```
/* createAudioPlayers
 * create audio players for each file in files */
function createAudioPlayers() {
    for (f in files) {
        var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
        $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
    }
}
```

But what I'm trying to do is invoke a specific player with a specific song of my choice instead of 5 of them at once which is how it currently works.

Like this:

```
<div id="audio-players1"></div>
<div id="audio-players2"></div>
<div id="audio-players3"></div>
<div id="audio-players4"></div>
<div id="audio-players5"></div>
```

I've tried to do this for both loops:

Replacing this:

```
$("#audio-players")
```

With this:

```
$("#audio-players" + f)
```

But then the buttons won't work.

Here's the code to pull the files from:

```
var files = ["interlude.mp3", // 0
            "chooseyourweapon.mp3", // 1
            "interlude.mp3", // 2
            "scriptures.mp3",
       "scriptures.mp3"// 3
            ];
```

And I'm unsure how to proceed, I'm still learning. **Thank you.**

Comment: what do you mean by "invoke a specific player with a specific song"?

Comment: @wolfram77 I'm pretty sure they mean that if they choose song 2, it brings up audio player 2 and plays song 2. If they choose song 5, it brings up audio player 5, and plays song 5. It shouldn't bring up other audio players, but it currently brings all 5 up.

Comment: @wolfram77 Thank you for replying.

It's just to clarify. Because right now the code is invoking 5 audio players at once with their own songs, but, I'm trying to invoke them **separately**, each one of them with their own song of course.

Comment: @PaydenK.Pringle Yes, exactly.

Comment: to keep just one player visible you can `$("audio-players"+files[i]).hide()` all the others. you can do it on a select `<select><option>interlude.mp3</option>...</select>` and listen to a "change" event.

Comment: Ah yes, the old trick of opening an SO account with a pic of an attractive female taken off the internet and giving a fake name hoping they get answers quicker..... Aaaanyway dude, you should just create your element and pass a param for the song to play to a method that switches to the desired one. All that extra stuff is just not necessary if I'm understanding your intent correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Life will become a lot simpler by doing the following in a *single* loop using `files.forEach(...)` (or the jQuery equivalent) :

- creating the `<audio>` elements
- creating the corresponding `<div>` elements
- attaching the play button's `.on('click' ...)` event handler

This approach will cause any assignments made within the loop to remain available to the event handler. This is a feature of javascript (and some other languages) called "closure".

```
/* createAudio
 * create audio elements and corresponding div elements in a single loop */
function createAudio() {
    files.forEach(function(fileName) {
        var $audio = $('<audio class="audio" preload="true"><source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/' + fileName + '"></audio>');
        var $player = $('<div class="audioplayer"><button class="play playbutton"></button><div class="timeline"><div class="playhead"></div></div></div>')

        $("#audio-players").append($audio).append($player);

        $player.find(".playbutton").on('click', function() {
            $audio.play(); // "closure" causes the variable `$audio` still to exist when the button is clicked, even though createAudio() and the iterator function have both completed and returned.
        });
        // Attach any further event handlers here (eg "stop", "pause")
    });
}
```

Note that the need for elements to have a unique ids disappears - unless of course they are needed for other purposes, though it's highly likely that the need disappears completely.

Comment: That's amazing, you're amazing, thank you a lot. But yes, I need them separated to tweak the .css for each one of them, my idea is just like in this photo - https://puu.sh/ynCqR/3cb9be0389.png.

Is it possible to get the elements out of the loop and call them separately with the full div element like in the below section I illustrated in the photo?

Comment: It sounds like you are using one directive per audio/player (for positioning). So with 4 items in the `files` array, you need 4 CSS directives. Even if the CSS directives are arbitrary, you will find it easier and more flexible to apply your CSS styling in javascript/jQuery. That way, one rule (or set of rules) will cater for a `files` array of any size. As a bonus, my single loop with do the job because you won't need IDs for applying styles ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:
https://codepen.io/wolfram77/pen/POOqmv

If you want to show only one player of a song:

```
function showPlayer(f) {
  for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    if(i===f) $("#audioplayer-"+i).show();
    else $("#audioplayer-"+i).hide();
  }
};
```

Now, lets create a select where we can choose which some:

```
<select id="select-songs"></select>
```

And, create the options for select and handle "change" event:

```
/* createSelectOptions
 * create select options for each file in files */
function createSelectOptions() {
    for (f in files) {
        var optionString = `<option value="${f}">${files[f]}</option>`;
        $("#select-songs").append(optionString);
    }
  $("#select-songs").on('change', function(el) {
    var f = parseInt($("#select-songs option:selected").val());
    console.log(f, files[f]);
    showPlayer(f);
  });
  showPlayer(0);
}
```

And finally, dont forget to execute it:

```
/* theDOMHasLoaded()
 * Execute when DOM is loaded */
function theDOMHasLoaded(e) {
    // Generate HTML for audio elements and audio players
    createAudioElements();
    createAudioPlayers();

    // Populate Audio List
    populateAudioList();
    populateComponentDictionary();
    createSelectOptions();
}
```